# Server MySQL automatically sets attribute "on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My Data Base has 2 Timestamp Columns, One for the Created on and one for the Last Update, When I create the data base using PHP and then check the table later in PHPMyadmin the first Timestamp column(createdon) has a DEFAULT value set to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and also has an "attribute" that says "on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP". I make these tables pragmatically so I can't go and change each one. I know I can set the DEFAULT to zero using SQL code, But How can I remove any potential "attributes" or "triggers" ?

Comment: Please show how you're creating the table. I don't see this automatic adding of the attributes: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cba32/2

Comment: It was a simple creat statement .

Comment: I used a simple `CREATE TABLE` statement and that didn't happen. You must be doing something different.

Comment: CREATE TABLE database ( createdon TIMESTAMP , lastupdat TIMESTAMP )

Comment: Are you using a tool like phpMyAdmin?

Comment: I have phpmyadmin on the server but I use php to create the table

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem with simply putting "DEFAULT 0"  in front of the first column.